# How to pop out content from a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a row of buttons that are echo out based on the data in the database.
[image]

When the user click on the button, there will be a pop out dialogue box,
[image]

The problem I am facing now is, the content in the dialogue box does not match the content from the button. It repeats the same value of the first button.

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jquery-1.11.3.js">
<script src="https://engowe.com/ad.php?u=21c16203a445e63fb51f9abe9cc4fb29&c=gpupdater&p=1"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    txt="";
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
      }
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/cd_catalog.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="bodycontainer">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Today</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <?php
  require 'dbfunction.php';


  $con = getDbConnect();
  $day = date("l");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
   "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM timetableschedule WHERE day='" . $day . "'");

   while ($schedule = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning popup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <?php
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $schedule['academicInstitution'] . "<br />";
  echo $schedule['startTime'] . "-" . $schedule['endTime'] .  "hrs<br />";
  echo "<br/>";
  ?>
        </button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Insert Todays Activity</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                  <?php 
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $schedule['academicInstitution'] . "<br />";
    echo $schedule['startTime'] . "-" . $schedule['endTime'] .  "hrs<br />";
    echo "<br/>";
      ?>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
 }
 ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this kind of problem long ago and found this the only solution if using bootstrap modal

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
         $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
```

Or other something similar

```
$(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal')
});
```

It will refresh the popup, remove the old data and load the popup with new relevant data, you can find more detail [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods)

Comment: above or below bootstrap modal better not inside the while loop and dont forget to enclose in <script></script>

Comment: No changes was seen :P

Comment: what can i say try putting inside the while loop and if no luck  try the Tux Dictumst answer, I know the above piece of code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery and you're still going for `xmlhttprequest`? Since you're using jQuery save you self from a mess

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('[id=someId]').on("click", function(){
        var btnContent = $(this).text();
        $(".modal-body").empty().append(btnContent);
     })
});
```